# Image is stretched on Safari with display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a codepen so you can see what I mean.
The a element gets its `height` from a script and the complete code works great on all devices except iOS.
On mobile Safari (I didnt test the desktop version yet) the image gets streched.
First I thought its because of the `height: 100%` i´d given it, but after removing it, it still wasnt working.

The goal was to get the image centered allways with flex. I use flex alot on that page, so I wanted to use it there as well.

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/gaboXK

EDIT: I tested it via browserstack on OS X and there is the same problem if you make the window small enough.

Comment: If you just want the image to fit centrally inside '.box' you should change the 'img' property 'max-width: none;' to 'max-width:100%;' and remove 'max-height: 100%;'.

Comment: But then the container wound not be filled with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams to be not possible right now because of a bug in Safari, Firefox and some others.

So I removed the flex properties and added some normal style to keep the image centered in its container.

```
.box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/dYYYxP

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed a considerable amount. I'll give you the highlights:

1. Narrowed down all `flex` properties. The only prefix needed is `-webkit` for Safari.
2. Set the `.body` `position: relative` and `height: 100vh and`width: 100vw`
3. Gave the inner `<div>` a name `.content`
4. Made `.box` a block-level `<section>`
5. Made the `.body` a `<main>`
6. Placed colored borders to display each element's position and size.

**>>>**[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/01/pen/xwGGBJ?editors=110)

**CSS**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: small-caps 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.frame {
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
.frame:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/818x435/000/fff.png&text=818x435);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 555;
}
.caption {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 1.8em;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption h2 {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 4;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: #000;
}
.caption p {
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="frame">
    <a class="content" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
      <div class="caption">

        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis.</p>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</main>
```

**UPDATE**: Here's a centered version **without** flexbox. I think there's a bug in Firefox and/or Safari when trying to overlay flex-items.

**>>>**[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/01/pen/KdprBZ)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, but thats not what i´m searching for. Now the Image has allways the full width of its container and not the full height.

Comment: Now the image isnt centered anymore... sorry. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: Sorry I dozed off -.- zzzzz I'm going to show you an old trick that keeps an image responsive and maintain it's ratio. Common ratios are 16:9 or 4:3 for video. Fortunately your image is close to 16:9. Then we can center it several ways, I'll try something simpler than flexbox, unless you are planning to extend your use of flexbox into your overall layout. That  may be a problem for me since I can't test Safari on a PC. :\

Comment: You can test is via Browserstack.com or in a virtual machine.

Comment: I tried that once a couple of years ago, my company had an account with them once. As soon as I get my lazy ass to unbox my new laptop, I'm going to make my old laptop run a VM. :\

Comment: The "bug" also appears in firefox. So you could test there... :)

Answer (score 0):

just set "align-self: center" for img or align-items: center for parent